# setter method is not actually setting anything

Tags: java, arrays, class, program-entry-point

i am currently stumped as to why my code isn't working right or rather not displaying the string value what I want.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] songNames = {
                "Array 1",
                "Array 2",
                "Array 3",
                "Array 4",
                "Array 5",
                "Array (...)",
                "Array 40",
        };

        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") String x : songNames)  {

            int minutes = 0; 
            int seconds = 0; 

            Song songTime = new Song(songNames, minutes, seconds);
            seconds = songTime.getSeconds();
            minutes = songTime.getMinutes();
            songNames = songTime.getSongName(songNames);

            Song SongTitle = new Song(songNames);
            songNames = SongTitle.getSongName(songNames);

            System.out.println(songNames + ":    " + minutes +
                " m " + seconds + " s.");
        }

    }
}
}
```

and this is the other class:

```
public class Song {


private String name;

/*the time durations are made up - random lengths
 */
private double minutes;
private double seconds;



public int getMinutes(){
    minutes = Math.random()*15;
    return (int) this.minutes;
}
public int getSeconds(){
    seconds = Math.random()*59;
    return (int) this.seconds;
}
public void setMinutes(int minutes){
    this.minutes= minutes;
}
public void setSeconds(int seconds){
    this.seconds= seconds;
}

public String getSongName() {
    return name;
}

public String setSongName(String name) {
    return   name = this.name;
}


public Song( int minutes, int seconds){
    this.minutes = getMinutes();
    this.seconds= getSeconds();
}

public Song(String name){
    this.getSongName();
    }
public Song (String[] songNames){

    name = setSongName(name);
}

}
```

Currently the output for name is null yet I want it to be "Array 1" but for some reason my coding is not working as intended obviously. what changes would I have to make in order for it to take in whatever array 1 is and display in the console. I have posted a similar thread in which someone else is taking the time to help me, but I fear he might have just stopped for the night. I am a beginner at java so please bear with my inexperience.

Comment: Does your code compile? You have messed up variable names names/songNames

Comment: Where are you printing from Names? Your main method declared a Names variable, then you write from an undeclared songNames variable. Also, you're never calling setSongNames. What are you doing, and what isn't working?

Comment: i think his class name should be `Song` instead of `Class1` because he having two constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where you are actually calling a *setter* method is in this constructor:

```
public Song (String[] Names){
    this.setName(songName);
}
```

But if you look carefully at that, you will see that you are calling the setter with the wrong arguments.  You are *ignoring* the `Names` parameter, and (in effect) setting `songName` to its current value.  That is a no-op; a "do nothing" action.

---

There are other errors in your code ... but I think you will learn more if you look for them yourself.

But I would like to point out a couple of important style issues:

- You should NEVER start a variable name with an uppercase letter.  Calling a variable `Names` is wrong.
- You should try to use names that are consistent, and non-misleading.

  For instance you have used `songName`, `getSongName` and `setSongName` for an attribute that is an *array* of strings.  Unless you *intend* to represent a single name as multiple strings (which sounds crazy to me), then `songName` should be `songNames` and so on.  (But in other places, you *do* use `songNames` or even `Name` ...  Be *consistent!!*)

Comment: I edited the code on the site so that it looks more like the one im using so its easier to read but I cant for the life of me get my getter method to actually get an array member. I believe the problem lies within the method not actually get the list of strings within the array. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: What you need to do is *understand* what the code you are writing actually does.  Randomly changing things too try to get your code to work is not programming.  In fact, I think that the root problem is exactly the same problem that I pointed out in my initial Answer.  Go and read my answer again ... carefully.